# JavaScript: How do I fire an event when a user has accessed the page via back/forward buttons?

Tags: javascript

There is a number of threads here on StackOverflow concerning how to catch the back/forward button, but that's not what I want to do. I want to fire a method each time a page is loaded by pressing the back/forward button. So not on the page, where the user clicked back/forward, but on the page that the user got to after clicking back/forward.

I also tried looking at events using Chrome and I haven't found any event that is firing when coming back or going forward to a page.

Comment: Probably using a cookie is your best bet? There doesn't seem to be anything about that in the [request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), and I'd imagine not all browsers would implement that (if it exists?) consistently anyway.

Comment: the cookie itself doesn't trigger an event. So your idea would be setup an interval for that?

Comment: This really depends on your front-end architecture and how your code handles History API events. Your *target* page won't get an event; it won't be able to tell if it was loaded by the "back" or "forward" button or by somebody clicking a bookmark, unless you have an architecture that can infer what's happening from custom headers or something. The History API in my experience is difficult to deal with if you want it to do things it doesn't want to do.

Comment: I never suggested that a cookie "triggers" anything. Cookies, being the only 'state management' that traditionally HTML has, have always been used to track users (and users' movements across your site). *Does that not sound related to what you're trying to do?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event

> The popstate event will be triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward button (or calling history.back() or history.forward() in JavaScript).

First you can save the info that user has navigated to localStorage or cookie, and then you can check if that localStorage entry or cookie exists on the **next page load event**.

If it exists, user has navigated to that page using back/forward buttons, you can do whatever you need to do, and clear the localStorage entry/cookie.